# Why does my Sudoku solver return an empty sudoky grid?

Tags: python, sudoku

I'm trying to create my own Sudoku solver in Python but it returns an empty sudoku grid.

I tried to visualize my code on pythontutor so i can see what's wrong but the numbers on the first row are corrects.

So i don't know why it returns an empty grid. By empty grid, i mean that it returns the exact same grid as the beginning. The 0's are not replaced by numbers.

Here's my code :

```
board = [
        [7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
        [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9],
        [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8],
        [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0],
        [9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5],
        [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7]
    ]

def valid(row, col, number):
    global board
    for i in range(0,9):
        if board[row][i]==number:
            return False
    
    for i in range(0,9):
        if board[i][col]==number:
            return False
    
    col_start = (col//3)*3
    row_start = (row//3)*3 

    for r in range(0, 3):
        for c in range(0, 3):
            if board[row_start+r][col_start+c]==number:
                return False
    return True

def solve_sudoku():
    global board
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if board[row][col]==0:
                for number in range(1,10):
                    if valid(row, col, number):
                        board[row][col] = number
                        solve_sudoku()
                        board[row][col] = 0
                return False


print(board)
solve_sudoku()
print(board)
```

Comment: what is an "empty grid"?

Comment: By empty grid, i mean that all the 0 are not replaced by numbers. I'm going to edit to be more precise

Comment: Mmm well I don't know anything about sodoku really, but your `solve_sudoku` function checks if a number is zero, `if board[row][col] == 0:` then you change it to a number: `board[row][col] = number` but then *right after that* you change it *back to zero*: `board[row][col] = 0`

Comment: ```if board[row][col] == 0:``` is for backtracking. It means that if no numbers are correct on a case, it will return to the previous case. I mean maybe i'm wrong because i'm still struggling to understand recusivity and backtracking. But I know for sure that the first row is successfully completed and i don't know why it returns the input grid.

Comment: I already explained to you, *any change* you are making to the global `board` object will be reversed by doing that. Think about it. You are telling it to change to some number, then right after, telling it to change back to `0`. Instead, don't rely on mutating a global board object. For example, pass the board as an argument, and when you make a recursive call, pass a copy of the board.

Comment: Note, your function **doesn't return anything**. It mutates a global object (bad practice in general). (well, it returns `False` sometimes, but that could be anything since you never actually use the return value)

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to change the variable board but it doesn't. I'm going to pass ```board``` as argument instead of using global

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to make this any clearer: **it does change the board**. But then you **change it back**. If I have a list, `x = [1,2,3]`. then I change the middle element, `x[1] = 99` but then I **change it back** `x[1] = 2` what else do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your return what your consider as empty grid where you put `board[row][col] = 0` in `def solve_sudoku():` in the part

```
                    if valid(row, col, number):
                        board[row][col] = number
                        solve_sudoku()
                        board[row][col] = 0
```

so values set to zero again after the recursive operation.

Looking for your next trial.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some coding convention feedback:

valid() uses range(0, N) while solve_sodoku() uses range(N). They are equivalent.
Better to be consistent. The latter is preferable because it is sparse.

Too much use of hard-coded number '9'. You should prefer len(board). Or set a constant
like: matrix_size = 9 and refer to matrix_size throughout. Think in terms of producing
a code set that would support an 8x8 board matrix by changing only the initial matrix.

for number in range(1,10) works but is disjointed vis-a-vis the rest of the code.
I suggest you try:

```
for i in range(len(board)):
    number = i + 1
    if valid(col, row, number)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.